# Pandas: Split multivalue columns based on the delimiters in the name

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a large Pandas dataframe where there are a number of multi-valued columns. These columns are have "/" in their names, and the values in these columns are also delimited by "/". Below is a minimal representative example of such a dataframe.

```
        Name   North / South   East / West   No1 / No2 / No3
0        ABC           0 / 1         0 / 0        10 / 3 / 6
1        XYZ           1 / 0         0 / 1         4 / 5 / 6
2        PQR           1 / 0         0 / 1         3 / 6 / 6
```

I would like to split up the columns. The straightforward way is to create a new column, then iterate along the length of the index populating it with the splitted up string along each element. But I will have to hardcode it for all the multi-valued columns.

Is there a more general way to do it? Perhaps scan through the df.columns then if an element contains "/" in it, run another function to break up that column? For the above dataframe, the desired output is as follows.

```
        Name  North  South  East  West  No1  No2  No3
0        ABC      0      1     0     0   10    3    6
1        XYZ      1      0     0     1    4    5    6
2        PQR      1      0     0     1    3    6    6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#get columns not contains / and set index
cols = df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains('/')].tolist()
df = df.set_index(cols)
print (df)
     North / South East / West No1 / No2 / No3
Name                                          
ABC          0 / 1       0 / 0      10 / 3 / 6
XYZ          1 / 0       0 / 1       4 / 5 / 6
PQR          1 / 0       0 / 1       3 / 6 / 6

#create new columns names
c = df.columns.to_series().str.split(' / ', expand=True).stack().values.tolist()
print (c)
['North', 'South', 'East', 'West', 'No1', 'No2', 'No3']

#list comprehension with split to df and concat output
df = pd.concat([df[x].str.split(' / ', expand=True) for x in df], axis=1)
print (df)
      0  1  0  1   0  1  2
Name                      
ABC   0  1  0  0  10  3  6
XYZ   1  0  0  1   4  5  6
PQR   1  0  0  1   3  6  6

#assign new columns names
df.columns = c
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  Name North South East West No1 No2 No3
0  ABC     0     1    0    0  10   3   6
1  XYZ     1     0    0    1   4   5   6
2  PQR     1     0    0    1   3   6   6
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True) 
print (df)

def f(df):
    return pd.concat([s.str.split(' / ').apply(pd.Series, index=c.split(' / ')) for c, s in df.set_index('Name').iteritems()], axis=1).reset_index()
print (f(df))

def f1(df):
    cols = df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains('/')].tolist()
    df = df.set_index(cols)
    c = df.columns.to_series().str.split(' / ', expand=True).stack().values.tolist()
    df = pd.concat([df[x].str.split(' / ', expand=True) for x in df], axis=1)
    df.columns = c
    return df.reset_index()
print (f1(df))

In [142]: %timeit (f(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 2.6 s per loop

In [143]: %timeit (f1(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 27.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I am having some issues running it. I think with df = df.set_index(cols) you have changed df. So when I run c = df.columns.to_series().str.split(' / ', expand=True).stack().values, it throws an error. Can you check the solution again?

Comment: It's fine. Mistake on my part. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad can help! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach

```
In [1417]: pd.concat([s.str.split(' / ').apply(pd.Series, index=c.split(' / ')) 
                     for c, s in df.set_index('Name').iteritems()],
                     axis=1).reset_index()
Out[1417]:
  Name North South East West No1 No2 No3
0  ABC     0     1    0    0  10   3   6
1  XYZ     1     0    0    1   4   5   6
2  PQR     1     0    0    1   3   6   6
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It does work for the toy example but Jezrael's is more general.